# How can I use get0 in my R package to search only within package namespace?

Tags: r, namespaces, package, arguments

Let's say I have an internal function in my package, call it `is_()`, which can be thought of as a more generalized version if `is()`. In particular, it searches for specialized functions that are used to tell whether the supplied object is the given class. For example, `is_()` might be programmed as:

```
is_ <- function(obj, class) {
  if (exists(paste0("is.", class))) {
     get0(paste0("is.", class))(obj)
  }
  else inherits(obj, class)
}
```

That way, if I'm doing argument checking in my package, I can run something like

```
is_(x, "numeric_vector")
```

where I've defined

```
is.numeric_vector <- function(x) is.numeric(x) && is.null(dim(x))
```

within my package.

A problem arises when `is.numeric_vector()` is defined outside my package, e.g., by another package the user has loaded. In that case, `exists()` and `get0()` both find the function wherever they can, but I want to restrict the search to function defined in my package and included in my package's namespace (i.e., all imported packages). The `envir` and `inherits` arguments seem to get at what I want, but I don't know how to supply them to get the result I want. How can I restrict `get0()` to only search for its argument within my package's namespace?

Comment: Do you have an actual example of a function conflict that you are working around that we could use for testing?

Comment: To recreate the problem, don't define `is.numeric_vector()` within the package and instead define it outside the package (i.e., in the global environment). `is_(1, "numeric_vector")` will return `TRUE` but I want it to return `FALSE` because `inherits(1, "numeric_vector")` is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your package namespace will inherit from the base namespace which inherits from the global environment. For a more detailed explanation, see here: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#namespaces. If you want more control over the symbol look up, you'll need to do the work yourself. You could include your own `get` function in your package

```
# These are private helpers that do not need to be exported from your package.
.pkgenv <- environment()
get1 <- function(name, env = .pkgenv) {
  if (identical(env, emptyenv())) {
    NULL
  } else if (identical(env, globalenv())) {
    # stop at global env
    NULL
  } else if (exists(name, envir=env, inherits = FALSE)) {
    env[[name]]
  } else {
    # try parent
    get1(name, parent.env(env))
  }
}
```

This will recursively search for the symbol in environments but stops at the global environment. You could use it with your `is_` function like

```
is_ <- function(obj, class) {
  if (!is.null(fn <- get1(paste0("is.", class)))) {
    fn(obj)
  } else {
    inherits(obj, class)
  }
}
```

Here we just check for null rather than separately verifying the name and then retrieving the value. If `get1` is something that will be called a bunch you might want to consider caching the result so you don't always have to walk the inheritance tree.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. Is there not a way to restrict the environment `get0()` searches in using its `envir` and `inherits` arguments? If the user attaches a package that contains `is_numeric_vector()`, then won't `is_()` still pick that up because its environment is the package from which it came and not the global environment?

Comment: User attached packages should not be in the inheritance chain. If you find a counter example, please share. There’s not a way to change how get0 works because that’s just how base R works. You could write your own if you prefer to manually iterate the patent environments.

Comment: This is happening in my own R package, `WeightIt`. The `is_()` function I use is similar to the one I posted here but replaces `paste0("is.", class)` with `paste0("is_", class)`. The `purrr` package has a function, `is_numeric()`, which produces a "Deprecated" warning. When `purrr` is attached by the user and `is_(x, "numeric")` is run, `purrr:is_numeric()` is retrieved by `get0()`. Your solution would not prevent that because `purrr:is_numeric()` is not in the global environment.

Comment: OK. I got the parent order wrong so yes, attached packages become the parents of the global environment. So there's no common way to stop searching at the global environment. I updated my answer to use an alternative to `get0` that will stop at the global environment.